Is there any way in Python to run code with parameters from string variable?
I am developing a website with interactable algorithms. The problem is that I get code as string from database and I need to execute it with parameters that came from user interface. Is there any Python library that can solve this problem?
I am new to Python and Django and I do not really know if this is possible or not.
Example of code:
class CombinationColex:
    def __init__(self, n, k):
        self.total_elements = n 
        self.combination_size = k 
        self.combination_array = [0] * (self.combination_size + 1)
        self.combination_array[self.combination_size] = self.total_elements + 2
        self.first()

    def first(self):
        for i in range(self.combination_size):
            self.combination_array[i] = i

    def next(self):
        if self.combination_array[0] == self.total_elements - self.combination_size:
            self.first()
            return self.combination_size
        j = 0
        while self.combination_array[j + 1] - self.combination_array[j] == 1:
            self.combination_array[j] = j
            j += 1
        self.combination_array[j] += 1
        return j

    def data(self):
        return self.combination_array[:-1]

    def Start(self):
        while True:
            for i in range(self.total_elements):
                present = i in self.data()
                print("1" if present else "0", end="")
            print()
            if self.next() == self.combination_size:
                break
combination_generator = CombinationColex(n, k)
combination_generator.Start()


You should not be taking this approach. Big security flaw.

Depending on what you what code you want to execute answers can vary but a general idea is to run user provided code in a sandboxed environment to avoid security issues with untrusted inputs.
Some ideas can be found on this previous question: How can I sandbox Python in pure Python? and here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191623/best-practices-for-execution-of-untrusted-code
And in the official wiki here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython
For example PyPy offers sandboxing directly: https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html
Another idea is to run directly the code provided in the browser with CPython compiled to WebAssembly (example here: https://testdriven.io/blog/python-webassembly/).
